# как мне изменить в цикле переменную hard на False? Может есть какая то функция которая возвращает только имя переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = []
easy = True
medium = True
hard = True

x.append(easy)
x.append(medium)
x.append(hard)
print(x)
for number in range(len(x)):
    if x[number].some_function(hard) == "hard":
        x[number] = False
print(x)
```

Comment: а `hard = False` чем не устраивает? какая изначально задача то была?

Comment: задача в том, что бы перебрать список и изменить одну переменную в цикле фор по ее названию

Answer (score 3):

Используйте словари

```
x = {name: True for name in ["easy", "medium", "hard"]}

x["hard"] = False
print(x)
```

Comment: Я так понял, что именно список нужен

Comment: я понимаю что есть словари. Мне просто интересно, можно ли это сделать в списке

Comment: Список не хранит информацию об именах переменных, которые были туда положены

Comment: Ну если ещё один список с именами сделать, то можно

Comment: Либо создавай список кортежей, где будет [(имя, значение)]

Comment: Тоже вариант хороший

Comment: ну а вообще как обратится к имени переменной? Существует такая опция? может даже не в списке

Comment: Нет, это бессмысленно

Comment: можно locals().items() или result = f'{переменная=}'.split('=')[0] или globals()   https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-get-variable-name-as-string

Comment: Через f строки в любом случае нужно будет указать имя переменной. Через globals не узнаешь и е сменишь значение. Уж тем более в списке, который вбирает только значения, без какой-либо информации о переменной

Comment: Это пустая затея, которая создает неудобства и автору и программе

Comment: Отчего же через globals() не узнаешь? def get_variable_name(variable):
    globals_dict = globals()
    return [var_name for var_name in globals_dict if globals_dict[var_name] is variable]

Comment: Хорошо, согласен, можно в цикле перебрать все переменные и на нужной остановиться и вывести значение. Но насколько это целесообразно? Как по мне, автору нужно объяснить, что это unpythonic, и есть способы лучше и проще

Comment: Я просто не знаю, что  автор вотроса делает, может отладчик :)

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении в список переменные теряют имя, в список попадают только их значения. Чтобы сохранить имя его нужно куда-то поместить. Можно сделать простейший класс, который будет хранить имя и значение и тогда можно будет делать примерно то, что вы хотите:

```
class Level():
    
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} = {self.value}'
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    
x = []
easy = Level('easy', True)
medium = Level('medium', True)
hard = Level('hard', True)

x.append(easy)
x.append(medium)
x.append(hard)
print(x)

for i in x:
    if i.name == 'hard':
        i.value = False
print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
[easy = True, medium = True, hard = True]
[easy = True, medium = True, hard = False]
```

Если у вас есть только имя и значение и нет объектов с повторяющимся именем, то вам на самом деле достаточно было бы и словаря из другого ответа. Но классы - более универсальное, расширяемое решение.

Хотя доступ к объектам списка не самый быстрый, если список будет большой, то всё же лучше смотреть в сторону словарей, хотя и в них можно помещать объекты, списки и т.д.

Comment: Хорошая идея с созданием класса. Спасибо за четкий ответ)